# Calculation diagonal elements of matrices multiplication in numpy package

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Is there any way to calculate the diagonal value of matrix C which is equal to numpy.matmul(A, B) without the need to calculation off-diagonal elements? Because I am working with two large matrices A and B and I only need to have diagonal elements of their multiplication in the rest of my code. And the run time is considerably large if I calculate the whole matrix C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the matrices A and B have the same shape or are uneven?

Comment: yes, they are in the same shape.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it as :

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
arr2 = np.array([[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]])

diag_elem = [sum(arr1[i,]*arr2[:,i]) for i in range(arr1.shape[0])]
print(diag_elem)
```

**output:**

```
[84, 216, 366]
```

which are the same diagonal elements you get using the `np.matmul`

```
print(np.matmul(arr1,arr2))
```

results in

```
array([[ 84,  90,  96],
   [201, 216, 231],
   [318, 342, 366]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may as well use numpy operator `einsum`. Read [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

For your particular case, you want to use

```py
np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A, B)
```

Which I find more readable than the accepted answer (understanding of Einstein notation provided).

In addition, accepted answer returns the solution as a `python list`, while this answer returns a `numpy array`, which is advantageous if you need to operate over such array.

Plus, this notation allows generalization to n-dimensional arrays (n>2).

---

In terms of runtime, this approach is much faster, as it leverages numpy's machinery to do the work, as opposed to a python for loop, which are quite slow operations.

Both approaches are naturally much faster than calculating product and then taking the diagonal.

### Tests:

#### Small matrices:

```py
A = np.random.random((1000,1000))
B = np.random.random((1000,1000))

%%timeit
np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A,B)
```

--> 2.07 ms ± 59.1 µs

```py
%%timeit
[sum(A[i,]*B[:,i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])]
```

--> 168 ms ± 2.19 ms

#### Larger matrices:

```py
A = np.random.random((13000,13000))
B = np.random.random((13000,13000))

%%timeit
np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A,B)
```

--> 660 ms ± 13.6 ms

```py
%%timeit
[sum(A[i,]*B[:,i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])]
```

--> 29.5 s ± 516 ms